# .asmx service works with example.com but gets 404.3 at www.example.com

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, asmx, iis-10

On IIS 10, Windows Server 2016 I have a service installed as an application virtual directory.  My binding for the site is *.example.com.

If I navigate to the service as http://example.com/svc/service.asmx, it works.  If I navigate using www.example.com, I receive a 404.3 Cannot be served because of the extension configuration.

What makes it even more confusing is that I have another web service in another virtual directory that works just fine under either URL.  Both of these services were originally running on a Windows 2003 server and have been migrated over.

Since this works without www, I don't think I need any kind of handler specified.  I'm stuck at knowing if this is an application configuration (web.config) or an IIS configuration issue, or both?

Comment: What does the _host_ `www` resolve to in `DNS` (does it point the same server)? Is there a separate binding for `www` in your server?

Comment: No separate binding and DNS is wildcard, every subdomain points to that address.  Binding is also wildcard (*.example.com).  A second service on the same domain works fine both with and without the www subdomain.  404.3 response page on the server references a MIME handler, but how can a handler be needed in one situation and not another?